# Get object from another part of a python script without activating the whole script

Tags: python

I have two python scripts: one script which triggers an API, and another script which I want to read information from the API call. That is, let's say script1 has a variable `"word"` that it grabs during its API call and I want script2 to be able to read it and print it.

I tried using the method of importing (this is pseudo-code):

```
import script1
print script1.word
```

The problem is the first API is a "polling" script, which activates and stays on. So, when I called the import, as soon I did anything in script2 related to the import from script1, the polling function was activated as part of script2's run. So, then I have two scripts running the API.

What I want is for script1 to just store the variable and for script2 to print it (or be able to use it however I want as a normal variable/object in script2).

I hope this makes sense. I can't come up with a simple example to past here because of the API. So, I'm having difficulty making this question more clear and I'd be happy to answer any questions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first script needs to put its actual polling in a block like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # do polling stuff
```

to have that logic execute when the script itself is executed but *not* also when it's imported.